# When reviewing answers, how can I view other answers for the post?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, answered-questions, review-queue

I was clearing the late posts, and there was an answer that was a correct answer to the question, so I hit "no action needed".

Turns out it was one of the "test" reviews. This question was already answered, and this answer was just a repeat of an existing answer.

Am I missing something? Why doesn't the review page display other answers? Do I need to start opening each complete post when I review?
.

Comment: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17299/158442

Comment: perfect. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the "link" button in the sidebar on the right.

Source: [muru's answer here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17299/158442) - it also has some related info.

Comment: rock on! I will delete my comments and throw you an upvote